# atlassian-python-api exception by using confluence.delete_attachment()

Tags: python, confluence-rest-api

i try to delete all attachments from a site with confluence.delete_attachment(page_id, filename, version), butt it throws always the same exception:
*requests.exceptions.HTTPError: 401 Client Error: Authorization Required for url:*

I am currently deleting the attachments as follows:

```py
from atlassian import Confluence

confluence_url = 'https://xxx/confluence/'
confluence_usr = os.environ.get('CONFLUENCE_CREDS_USR')
confluence_psw = os.environ.get('CONFLUENCE_CREDS_PSW')
confluence = Confluence(url=confluence_url, username=confluence_usr, password=confluence_psw)

# Check site response, if site not reachable, check 5 times every 5 sec
response = resilient_confluence_http_get_request(f'{confluence_url}rest/api/content/{page_ids[csv_file]}')
# Check site response, if site not reachable, check 5 times every 5 sec
attachment = confluence.get_attachments_from_content(page_ids[csv_file])
print(f"attachment type: {type(attachment)}")
print(f"attachment content:\n {attachment}\n\n")
att_to_del = []
indices = 0
for i in attachment['results']:
    print(f"id type: {type(attachment['results'][indices]['id'])}")
    att_to_del.append(attachment['results'][indices]['id'])
    indices += 1
print(f"delete attachments with id's {att_to_del}")
for id_to_delete in att_to_del:
    response = requests.delete(f'https://xxx/confluence/rest/api/content/{id_to_delete}',
        auth=(confluence_usr, confluence_psw))
```

The delete function is the only one that doesn't work. What am I doing wrong?

Here i try to delete with confluence.delete_attachment(...):

```
def response_wait_repeat():
    attachments = confluence.get_attachments_from_content('my_site_id')
    print(attachments)
    confluence.delete_attachment('my_site_id', 'my_filename', version=None)
```

Comment: Where is your authorisation (log-in) handled?

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are using [`atlassian-python-api`](https://pypi.org/project/atlassian-python-api/)

as the examples on the pypi documentation, you first need to create a connection to the confluence:

```py
from atlassian import Confluence

confluence = Confluence(
    url='http://localhost:8090',
    username='admin',
    password='admin')

status = confluence.create_page(
    space='DEMO',
    title='This is the title',
    body='This is the body. You can use <strong>HTML tags</strong>!')

print(status)
```

If you are still getting this error (`401 Authorization Required`) I would check manually in confluence, whether you have the permission to do these such actions.
It's probably the case, because you are saying the only action you cannot preform is delete.

otherwise I would contact the confluence admin.

Comment: Hi Mogi,
thank you for the answer.

But why can I delete the attachments with requests.delete, here I use the same authentication. Strange ...

Comment: So can you please edit your question and post more parts of your code, so we can find the specific problem you have? And tell us where exactly the exception occurs

Comment: i have edit my question. the exception occurs on the confluence.delete(..) call.

Comment: do you use the same confluence object? post the full code.
Did you try manually deleting the attachment? using the browser not the api

Comment: So, here is the full code where i now delete the attachment. i want to replace the for loop with the request call, with delete.attachment(). manually deleting the attachment ist no problem also with requests.delete(...).  i use the same confluence object to get the attachments and upload the attachments.

Comment: so which one is working? `requests.delete` or `confluence.delete_attachment`?

Comment: requests.delete